# Can I create a new SensorEvent object to test onSensorChanged() function?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to test the function

```
onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event){..}
```

on the emulator. 
I want to create a new SensorEvent object. I found a nice link:

http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/sensor/SensorEvent.html#SensorEvent%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20javax.media.j3d.Sensor,%20javax.media.j3d.Transform3D,%20int[],%20int,%20long,%20long%29

but I don't know how to create argument

```
Transform3D sensorRead
```

So, how I create Transform3D object or new SensorEvent one? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this will do you any good.  AFAIK, there's no relationship between android.hardware.SensorEvent and com.sun.j3d.utils.behaviors.sensor.SensorEvent.

From a brief look at the Android source code, it looks like there's simply no way to create your own SensorEvent object.  This is a serious oversight on Google's part, if you ask me.

Edit:  Here's what I do.  I write a method named sensorChanged(Sensor sensor, float[] values) to do all the work, and just call it from the regular onSensorChanged() method.  Then, when I want to test sensor handling from within my app, I call sensorChanged() with whatever values I want.  I might not be able to create a SensorEvent object, but this way I can still test my code.