# How to call a method from an anonymous class

Tags: java, android

I have this class that detects when the phone is facing up and when is facing down and prints on the screen Face Up or Face Down!!

```
package com.example.kyriakos.androiddetectflipping;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public  class Test extends Activity {

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometerSensor;
    boolean accelerometerPresent;

    TextView face;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_detect_flipping);

        face = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.face);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if(sensorList.size() > 0){
            accelerometerPresent = true;
            accelerometerSensor = sensorList.get(0);
        }
        else{
            accelerometerPresent = false;
            face.setText("No accelerometer present!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(accelerometerPresent){
            sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerListener, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        if(accelerometerPresent){
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerometerListener);
        }
    }

    public SensorEventListener accelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {

            float z_value = arg0.values[2];
            if (z_value >= 0){
                face.setText("Face UP");
            }
            else{
                face.setText("Face DOWN");
            }
        }};


}
```

Now i want to print the message from an another class

```
package com.example.kyriakos.androiddetectflipping;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Flip extends AppCompatActivity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

}}
```

It think that onSensorChanged method is responsible for printing the message so I tried to call the method onSensorChanged inside Class Flip like this

```
    SensorEventListener ob = new SensorEventListener();
    ob.onSensorChanged;
```

But it is wrong because SensorEventListener is an anonymous inner class!!So my question is how can i call this method?I read about how to call a method from an anonymous inner class but i don't understand it very well.Sorry if my question is stupid but i am new to java,android and i am trying to learn

Comment: Where do you want to call that method? Is it inside `Flip onCreate()` method?

Comment: Yes i want to call it inside the Flip Class

Comment: If you want to call `onSensorChanged` method, you need a `SensorEvent ` object right? I could n't find `SensorEvent` object anywere in your code

Comment: Something like this ?`SensorEvent ob = new SensorEvent();
ob.onSensorChanged();`

Comment: No, `SensorEventListener` is not an anonymous class. Look! There's the name right there: `SensorEventListener`!

Answer (score 1):

You' re  not assigning the anonymous class, but its base class to `ob`. If you want to access it and use it's overloaded methods you'd have to do:

```
Test test = new Test();
SensorEventListener ob = test.accelerometerListener;
```

Then you can call your overriden method on it.

Comment: Thank you now i think i understand my mistake so i do it like this `Test test = new Test();
SensorEventListener ob = test.accelerometerListener; ob.onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0); ` but now it says tha it can't resolve arg0 :/ Am i doing something wrong again?thank you in advance

Comment: You have to provide an argument for that. You'd have to perform it providing a `SensorEvent`. You can create `sensEvent` by creating it somehow (I don't know the ways of constructing it). Then you call the method as `ob.onSensorChanged(sensEvent)`. It's usually provided by Android. There has been a question about it earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734850/can-i-create-a-new-sensorevent-object-to-test-onsensorchanged-function.